# Game Engine: how to switch scenes in python code

Tags: python, game-engine, scene

I need to be able to switch scenes in python code while in game, and I don't mean hooking up a python controller to a scene changing actuator, I need to be able to change scenes without it. Does anyone know how it would be done?

Comment: What are the reasons why you think you "...need to be able to change scenes without it."

Answer (score 3):

It does exist in the API, the trick is you have to get the scene first:

```
for scene in bge.logic.getSceneList():
    if scene.name == 'oldSceneName':
        scene.replace('newSceneName')
        break
```

API:
https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bge.types.KX_Scene.html#bge.types.KX_Scene.replace

---

Another useful 'replace scene' like thing that I have done quite a lot is to end the current scene(s) and then add the new one:

```
for scene in bge.logic.getSceneList():
    scene.end()
bge.logic.addScene('sceneNameGoesHere')
```

Answer (score 0):

The [BGE API](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_1/bge.logic.html) (version 2.77) does not support to switch scenes without an actuator.

The scene actuator is sufficient enough.

- You will never be able to switch to more than one scene. [dynamic number of switches]
- You already can dynamically setup the scene to switch to. [dynamic calculation of the target scene]
- A scene switch will always performed AFTER the current frame (after the actuators where processed). [timing]

## Remark:

You can dynamically add overlay/background scenes via addScene(). This is to add several scenes within a single frame without the need to know the number of scenes beforehand. (Otherwise you need n actuators for n scenes to add).